# Support mobile and noscript scenarios + maintain performance

Tags: html, mobile-website, noscript

I'm building a website that is composed of multiple sections. Instead of splitting my content up into multiple HTML pages, I'm planning to use URL fragments to each section (primarily for performance reasons; I don't want a full-page reload for every single page). Imagine something like the following:

```
<section id="portfolio">
  <a href="#project1">Link to Project 1</a>
  <a href="#project2">Link to Project 2</a>
  ....
  <a href="#project20">Link to Project 20</a>
</section>
<section id="project1>
  Content for Project 1 <img src="project1.jpg" />
</section>
<section id="project2>
  Content for Project 2  <img src="project2.jpg" />
</section>
...
```

This poses some obvious difficulties

1. The browser will load up the entire website's HTML, which can slow down rendering on mobile devices
2. The browser will request every image in every section; else I'll have to add JS that lazy-loads the images when the section comes into view

To at least partially get around this, I was planning to split the sections up into HTML partials. Then load the partials using AJAX. However this means that I'm now relying on JS to provide essential functionality for a website.

My questions are:

1. Are supporting noscript and mobile scenarios necessarily always conflicting aims?
2. Should I just accept full-page reloads for each section and make separate HTML files?
3. Is there a way to gracefully handle both noscript scenario and loading performance, if I were to go with my existing approach?
4. Are resources inside `<noscript>` elements ignored unless JS is disabled?

Comment: `<noscript></noscript>`?

Comment: Answer to Q3: No. In noscript scenario, you could only load all the images at the beginning.

Comment: Just a little question: Why are you taking great care on noscript scenario? It is 2017! Who will bother to block javascript?

Comment: @ppajer I do know about `<noscript>` but can't quite put together a solution for my problem with it. Are resources inside a `<noscript>` element ignored unless JS is disabled?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy 1) Privacy/security-conscious people 2) People with screen-readers 3) Search engines (though I've heard Google executes JS now). Plus professional pride about being able to code a simple website without leaning on JS for critical functionality :-)

Comment: AFAIK resources inside `<noscript>` blocks aren't downloaded unless the block is rendered, ie when JS is disabled. [Play around with this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/qkrphd4v/) and the devtools network tab, try removing the `noscript`.

Comment: @Jayraj Do you want to save time for loading, or you don't want the site to look bad during the loading process? If you want to tackle both problems, you would need a purpose to do so, I suppose :)

Comment: @Jayraj Elements inside `<noscript>` will be displayed only when js is not supported and ignored otherwise. But I've experienced situations that the elements inside noscript tag are displayed in plain text, i.e. the html code is directly displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, wrapping a copy of the HTML with all sections loaded in a `<noscript>` tag would be sufficient. The resources and DOM inside will only be rendered if JS is disabled, and the rest of the site can still benefit from AJAX. The downside is that you're bloating your file with duplicate HTML.

#### 1) Are supporting noscript and mobile scenarios necessarily always conflicting aims?

No, you can combine mobile and noscript with responsive images. Set a default src to a mobile resolution image, then use JS to switch it to a larger version if needed. This way even if JS is disabled, bandwidth is saved. This is one of the reasons why mobile-first development is a thing.

#### 2) Should I just accept full-page reloads for each section and make separate HTML files?

With the solution above you don't have to. But keep in mind that with proper caching and good resource management (ie minimal number of requests, good compression, optionally inlined above-the-fold stuff), full page loads are not that evil on mobile.

#### 3) Is there a way to gracefully handle both noscript scenario and loading performance, if I were to go with my existing approach?

Yes. I would suggest combining everything mentioned above, use responsive images with a mobile first default src and lazy loading on the page, and assume low bandwidth inside the `<noscript>` copy of your HTML. This way only the smallest required images are loaded if JS is enabled or disabled.

#### 4) Are resources inside  elements ignored unless JS is disabled?

Yes they are. Try removing the `noscript` from [this fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppajer/qkrphd4v/) and see what happens in the devtools network monitor.

Comment: "The downside is that you're bloating your file with duplicate HTML." - I might end up automating the process of inserting all my section partials into the `<noscript>` section so I don't have to look at a massive HTML file while I'm developing.